# else if and else statement are ignored

Tags: c#, winforms, date, metadata

I'm working on an Windows Form application which needs to search pictures by date taken in their metadatas. It compares when the date is between 2 selected dates or on 1 exact date. Here's the code :

```
private void searchByDate(Tag tag, String pic)
    {
        if (tag.ToString().Contains("Date/Time Original"))
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{4}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\b");
            Match m = regex.Match(tag.ToString());
            DateTime dateFound;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(m.ToString(), "yyyy:MM:dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateFound);

            Console.WriteLine(dateFound);

            if (checkEnd && dateFound != null) if (dateFound >= date && dateFound <= dateEnd) Console.WriteLine("Date found between"); //foundPictures.Add(pic);
            else if (dateFound != null) Console.WriteLine("single date found");//foundPictures.Add(pic);
            else Console.WriteLine("No dates found");
        }
    }
```

The if statement works fine, but when checkEnd (which is a checkBox for finding between two dates) is not checked, the others statements are totally ignored and I just can't find out why. Here's the console output for date between :

```
16.09.2017 00:00:00
Date found between
16.09.2017 00:00:00
Date found between
07.12.2016 00:00:00
Date found between
```

For searching exact date (16.09.2017)

```
16.09.2017 00:00:00
16.09.2017 00:00:00
07.12.2016 00:00:00
```

And with a random date (01.01.1753)

```
16.09.2017 00:00:00
16.09.2017 00:00:00
07.12.2016 00:00:00
```

As you can see the given datas are always the same. I tried to put another Console.WriteLine(); after these statements and it's showed. No exception is given.

**Edit :** To clarify things, I was aware that braces weren't required in a if statement, but not aware it was the case only for a single instruction. I though it was based on the line. Lack of experience, no one to teach me and not enough reasearch leaded me to ask this stupid question.

Comment: Try formatting your code, one `if` per line, and use brackets. It might help you see what's going on.

Comment: I should think that step debugging would have shown the code not going to the line or statement you expected (or hoped)

Comment: Editors: please do not change the indentation of OPs code. The problem is related to that indentation.

Comment: @OnStandBy I would read up on how to nested if else statement and learn how  to format and understand what code blocks are when using `{ }`

Comment: @MethodMan I know that, but I though that brackets were implicit on this case like this : if() "{" if () //do something; "}" . But I'll follow your advice as I could missed some details.

Comment: @OnStandBy here is a rule of thumb to use and or follow in the future, when executing more than 1 statement / command in a switch case statement wrap those multiple calls around `{ } ` which we call `Code Block` this will make for debugging and readability much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you format your code you will see that the way if/else is coded will never do anything if `checkEnd` is false.

```
if (checkEnd && dateFound != null)
{
    if (dateFound >= date && dateFound <= dateEnd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Date found between"); //foundPictures.Add(pic);
    }
    else if (dateFound != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("single date found");//foundPictures.Add(pic);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No dates found");
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: Never put if statements in a if statements without brackets.